# bibliography error

Tags: bibtex

I am using the following code to include my references:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
```

There is one generated item in .bbl file:

```
\bibitem[DD05]{DaaaDbbb05} ....the content...
```

The problem is that since both authors' name starts from D, the system automatically generates the abbreviation DD05. With DD05, there is an compiling error. If I change this item by DeD05 for example in the .bbl file, it will work. Do you know what is wrong? It is not the first time for me to meet this problem.

Here is my bib entry:

```
@article {DaaaDbbb05On,
AUTHOR = {Daaa, Xcccc and Dbbbb, Fffff},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 JOURNAL = {Sample journal},
 VOLUME = {1},
 YEAR = {2005},
 NUMBER = {1},
 PAGES = {1--17},
 }
```

The compiling error is

```
 ./my_thesis:133:Undefined control sequence \bibitem[DD05]{DaaaDbbb05On}
```

Comment: perhaps you should add the whole entry from your .bib file to the question, by way of example

Comment: Just added the bib entry. :-)

Comment: I could'nt reproduce the problem here... Maybe you should add more real examples of your code... (Before anything, you could try to delete the .aux and .bbl files and rerun latex)

Comment: Thanks henrique. The problem still exists if I delete .aux and .bbl files. I will temporarily change the Second author's name from "Dbbbb" to "Fbbbb", which works.

Comment: what is the error? It is in the LaTeX run I presume. Also as mentioned give a full minimal example file that generates it. Without it there's not way to guess the issue.

Comment: Please post the compiling error you mentioned.

Comment: Dear Frank, I am compiling a big project (my thesis). I'll try to test in a minimal example.

Comment: Dear Henrique, I add the error in formation in my post. I am using Kile under Ubuntu. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but do you *need* to use the alpha bibliography style?  Simply switching to plain should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks cm2. It works well if I switch to plain. I will temporarily keep like this. Latter, I would like to use alpha style, since it is more readable. :-) Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I created an minimal example based on your code snippet. Whatever I get **no errors**:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {DaaaDbbb05On,
AUTHOR = {Daaa, Xcccc and Dbbbb, Fffff},
 TITLE = {A sample paper},
 JOURNAL = {Sample journal},
 VOLUME = {1},
 YEAR = {2005},
 NUMBER = {1},
 PAGES = {1--17},
 }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{DaaaDbbb05On}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Results in
[image]